# How to get list of available languages for a SharePoint site using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Is there a way or a script to get a list of the available languages for a SharePoint site in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do it (untested):

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://servername:22222/sites/Test/"
# show the available languages
($site.RootWeb).RegionalSettings.InstalledLanguages | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
```